# iterable.length has been deprecated

Tags: reactjs, redux, draftjs

I am trying to use react-draft-wysiwyg with redux. My code looks like:

```
<Editor
  editorState={this.props.editorsState[el.i]}              
  onEditorStateChange={e => this.props.onSaveColumnEditorState(e, el.i) }          
/>
```

And reducer:

```
case editorTypes.UPDATE_COLUMN_EDITOR_STATE:     
  return {
    ...state,
    editorsState: Object.assign({}, state.editorsState, {[action.payload.columnUUID]: action.payload.editorState}),
  };
```

Redux state is updated successfully(checked redux tools) but I keep getting annoying warnings for every key press:

> iterable.length has been deprecated, use iterable.size or
>   iterable.count(). This warning will become a silent error in a future
>   version. Error
>       at Map.get (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/draft-js/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js:4650:21)
>       at baseIsTypedArray (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/lodash-es/_baseIsTypedArray.js:60:81)
>       at arrayLikeKeys (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/lodash-es/_arrayLikeKeys.js:32:120)
>       at keys (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/lodash-es/keys.js:37:167)
>       at baseGetAllKeys (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/lodash-es/_baseGetAllKeys.js:18:16)
>       at getAllKeys (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/lodash-es/_getAllKeys.js:16:85)
>       at equalObjects (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/lodash-es/_equalObjects.js:30:89)
>       at baseIsEqualDeep (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/lodash-es/_baseIsEqualDeep.js:88:83)
>       at baseIsEqual (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/lodash-es/_baseIsEqual.js:27:86)
>       at equalObjects (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/lodash-es/_equalObjects.js:65:39)

Warnings only appeared after I moved the state from react component to redux. What could be causing the warning & how to remove it?

Comment: so...what's the question?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: We are facing same issue in a bunch of different places on our app. Subscribing

Comment: facing a similar issue, does anyone know the rootcause

Comment: In my case, the issue was using Lodash clone deep (_.cloneDeep) with Immutable.js.